# Where to get Flash Player for Android 2.2 Froyo

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.2-froyo, adobe-flash

As everyone knows, the development of Adobe Flash for mobile devices was discontinued. I have an external device I want to access. It has a web server installed running a HTML script with an embedded Flash movie.

Since I am not able to download a compatible Flash version on Google Play and have a device that runs Android 2.2.1 Froyo and another device that runs 4.0.3 Android Ice Cream Sandwich, my question is: **Where can I get an Android version of Flash Player that may run on Froyo as well as on Android 4.0.3 ICS?**

I've downloaded the APK files [here](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Adobe-Flash-Player-Android-App_47084648.html). NOTE: I am no way affiliated with chip.de

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the apks for Flash for all versions of Android directly from Adobe in their old version archives.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

Scroll down a bit and you'll find "Flash Player for Android 4.0 archives" and "Flash Player for Android 2.x and 3.x archives".  These include the last versions of each released before Abode dropped Flash for Android.

Comment: Awesome, this helped me very much =) Thank you ;)